# Codeigniter Query result returning Custom result object with setters

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, codeigniter-2

How exactly does CI custome object works ?

As per CI documentation You can also pass a string to result() which represents a class to instantiate for each result object (note: this class must be loaded)

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users;");

foreach ($query->result('User') as $row)
{
   echo $row->name; // call attributes
   echo $row->reverse_name(); // or methods defined on the 'User' class
}
}
```

This is a very nice feature yet what Ci does is it will return an array of `User` objects and set attributes from row to it.

i have a problem with it that i want to have more control on what attributes to be publicly accessed and what to be modified before setting/getting.

how can i accomplish this ? can i tell CI to pass all attributes to constructor so that class can populate its own data ?

example class User

```
class User{
    private $data=array();
    protected $CI;
    //public $id,$name,$dob,$gender,$role,$username,$password,$salt,$picture,$lastactive;
    function __construct($data=null)
    {
        $this->data = $data; // i want to save data to a private var and allow attr. throu getters only
    }
    function set_password($p){
      $this->generateSalt();
      $this->data->password = $p.$this->data->salt;
    }
}
```

In a nutshell::

I want to use custom_result_object but i dont want codeigniter to populate class attributes for me, instead i want the class to receive those attrs and populate it him self the way he this its appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found your question while looking for a solution for myself.

After digging a bit in the documentation I managed to figure it out:

```
class user_item {
  // you can declare all the attributes you want as private
  private $id,$name,$dob,$gender,$role,$username,$password,$salt,$picture,$lastactive;

  function __construct(){
    // you can use the constructor to format data as needed
    $this->username = strtouppper($this->username);  
  }

  public function set_password($p){
    $this->generateSalt();
    $this->password = $p.$this->salt;
  }

  public function get_password(){
    return $this->password;
  }
}
```

Once set up, you can instantiate this class from `$this->db->result()`

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {
   public function get_user($id){
     return $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id), 1)->result('user_item');
   }
}
```

And call any public method or attribute of the class as needed

```
class Users extends CI_Controller {
  function __construct(){
     $this->load->model('user');
  }
  public function profile($user_id){
    var $myUser = $this->user->get_user($user_id);
    $myUser->set_password('myPassword');
    echo $myUser->get_password();
  }
}
```

I have simplified the code to make it clearer, but you get the idea.

Comment: Where did you put the user_item class however? In libraries?

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper I will put it in the same file as User_model. So it's auto-loaded when you do `$this->load->model('user')`.

Comment: Ok thanks! Too bad it seems they didn't put any documentation about that

Answer (score 0):

this example controller using result array and object

```
if ($this->session->userdata('id_jurusan') ==1) {
            $where=array('id_jurusan'=>$this->session->userdata('id_jurusan'));
            $value = $this->session->userdata('id_jurusan');
            $value2 = $this->session->userdata('username');
            $data['rule']=$this->guru_mod->get_where($where,'forward_changing')->result();
            $data['fuzzy']=$this->guru_mod->get_data_all('fuzzy')->result();
            $data['artikel']=$this->guru_mod->get_data_all('artikel')->result();
            $data['kondisi']=$this->guru_mod->get_where($where,'kondisi')->result();
            $data['artikel2'] = $this->guru_mod->get_data_all2('artikel','id_jurusan',$value);
            $data['riwayat_rule'] = $this->guru_mod->get_data_all2('forward_changing','username',$value2);
            $data['kondisi_rule'] = $this->guru_mod->get_data_all2('kondisi','id_jurusan',$value);
            $this->load->view('guru/daftar_rule',$data);
        }
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written